# java portable app with derby database

Tags: java, netbeans, portability

ok i want to make a portable jar file with derby database . My table is only for read .so i only make a search above i have my code . that i want is to explain to me how i can take derby database where i should paste it on my files  and what is the right  path to read in any device i run it ... ty 
when i create the jar file has only the code not the dabase ...

here is my code with the connection and the search query

```
package ARMY;

import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver;

/**
 *
 * @author Ccompany
 */
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu
     */
    public Menu() {
        initComponents();
        findUsers();
    }
 String driver ="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"; 
     String url ="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ABYP;create=true";
     String user ="db";
     String pass ="sql!123";


      public Connection getConnection()
     {
         Connection con;
      try {
         Class.forName(driver);  
         con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
         return con;
       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       }

     }

      public ArrayList <Tablearray>ListUsers(String ValToSearch){
      ArrayList <Tablearray> usersList  = new ArrayList <Tablearray>();
      Statement st;
      ResultSet rs;

      try {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM ABYP WHERE  Id_Search||Tyl||Apothkh||Parathrhseis||Ti LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%'";
          // String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM ABYP WHERE CONCAT ('Id_Search) LIKE '%||"+ValToSearch+"||%'";
            //String searchQuery = "SELECT *FROM ABYP where ID_SEARCH =? ";
            rs = st.executeQuery(searchQuery);
      Tablearray tablearray;
      while (rs.next()){
      tablearray = new Tablearray (
        rs.getString("Id_Search"),
        rs.getString("Tyl"),
        rs.getString("Apothkh"),
        rs.getString("Parathrhseis"),
        rs.getString("Ti")
          );
      usersList.add(tablearray);
      }
      }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return usersList;


      }
      public void findUsers()
    {
        ArrayList<Tablearray> users = ListUsers(jText_Searchh.getText());
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Id_Search","Tyl","Apothkh","Parathrhseis","Ti"});
        Object[] row = new Object[5];

        for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
        {
            row[0] = users.get(i).getid_Search();
            row[1] = users.get(i).gettyl();
            row[2] = users.get(i).getapothkh();
            row[3] = users.get(i).getparathrhseis();
            row[4] = users.get(i).getti();
            model.addRow(row);
        }
       jTable_Userss.setModel(model);

    }
```

my derby data i think is locate it on my derby netbeans folder should i copy paste the log file with seg0 file somewhere ? finnaly i insert all the rows from netbeans derby database and not with create table method is that ok for make it portable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i find the answer after some test for those who want to make it work   we clean and build the folder after change the connection url to this

```
 String driver ="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"; 
     String url ="jdbc:derby:.\\ABYP";
     String user ="db";
     String pass ="sql!123";
```

Then we copy the files from netbeans project  dist file the below (lib,jar,readme) and we paste it on a file in our usb after we copy the dabase folder e.x ABYP that contains the log seg and what else  from derby netbeans destination . and we paste it on our usb folder together the it works fine !!!